# Regex to find two words

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

I have the following data in a LibreOffice Calc cell:

**cell a1**

something

something2

Fill necessary details for XXX-deposit into account


**cell a2**

something

something2

Fill necessary details for XXX-cash over counter

I want to match the strings `something` and `something 2` in all cells to replace with another word `new` using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the replacement without actually using regex mode:

**Find:**

```
(something|something2)
```

**Replace:**

```
new
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
^.*\n.*(\nFill necessary details)
```

and replace with `new$1`.

Basically, the pattern matches any string that starts with 2 lines and the third starts with `Fill necessary details`. The part of the pattern wrapped with a pair of unescaped parentheses forms a capturing group whose contents can be referenced to with the help of a `$1` backreference.

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `.*` - 1st line, 0+ chars other than line breaks
- `\n`  - a newline
- `.*` - 2nd line, 0+ chars other than line breaks
- `(\nFill necessary details)` - Group 1 (referenced to with `$1` backreference): newline + `Fill necessary details` literal string.

See the screenshot:
[image]